# Getting values from an array

Tags: java, arrays

So let's say I have an array called `arr` with the values `&&&&.&&`. I want to find the number of ampersands (&) that are after the decimal point and store the value into `numDecimalDigits`.

```
int numDecimalDigits = 0;

char[] arr = new char[7]

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i ++)
{
    for (int decimal = (arr[pos] = '.'); decimal <= arr.length; decimal ++)
    {
        numDecimalDigits += 1;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the right approach. So the outside `for` loop runs through each index value of the array. The inner `for` loop starts at the decimal, and ends at the end of the array. Every time a new value is found, `numDecimalDigits` is added by one. However, in my code I think `numDecimalDigits` is returning an incorrect value.

Comment: What is this supposed to be doing -- `(arr[pos] = '.')`?  What it does is set arr[pos] to '.' (whatever *pos* is).

Comment: Well what I tried doing was to start the `for` loop at where the decimal point began, and end the loop at the end of the array. `pos` is just short for "position" (i.e. position in array)

Comment: Using indexOf on a String would make more sense.  Or a single loop from 0 to array.length, comparing to '.'.  (And you compare for equal with `==`.  `=` is assignment.)

Comment: `(arr[pos] = '.')` doesn't tell you where the decimal point is, it assigns '.' to `arr[pos]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one loop：

```
boolean foundDot = false;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] == '.') {
        foundDot = true;
    } else if(foundDot) {
        numDecimalDigits ++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use array. It would be easy like this:(Assuming `str` value must contains **one** '`.`' )

```
    int numDecimalDigits = str.split("\\.")[1].length();
```

Or you can do by subtracting `str.length()-1` with `indexOf(".")`

```
    int numDecimalDigits = str.length()-1 - str.indexOf(".");
```

Comment: Wouldn't make a lot more sense to use indexOf and not bother creating new strings you don't need??

Comment: @HotLicks which _new string_ you are referring to?

Comment: The two strings created by split. (Not to mention the String array.)

Comment: Ok, I have added your suggestion.